# Find local maxima, minima or saddle points: $f(x, y)=\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right) e^{-\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

- Find local maxima, minima or saddle points: $f(x, y)=\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right) e^{-\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

My attempt:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-2 x e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}-1\right)$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-2 y e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}-1\right)$

$\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x^{2}}=e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}\left(4 x^{4}+2 x^{2}\left(2 y^{2}-5\right)-2 y^{2}+2\right)$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y^{2}}=e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}\left(x^{2}\left(4 y^{2}-2\right)+4 y^{4}-10 y^{2}+2\right)$

$\frac{\partial^{2} f}{\partial x \partial y}=4 x y e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}-2\right)$

Now will find critical points

$$-2 x e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}-1\right)=0$$

$$-2 y e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}-1\right)=0,$$

hence $(0,0)$ and $\left\{(x, y): x^{2}+y^{2}=1 \quad , \quad x, y \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$ are ciritical points.

Now, **What should I do? May you help?**

Comment: Note that the function only depends on $(x^2+y^2)$, so you can substitute $r^2=x^2+y^2$. That might simplify things a bit.

Comment: @YiFan So there are infinitely many points... hence how can I use second derivative test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Hessian: at the point $(0,0)$:
$$f_{xx}=2>0,D=f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}=2\cdot 2-0^2>0 \Rightarrow f(0,0) \ \text{is a local minimum}$$
at the point $x^2+y^2=1$:
$$f_{xx}=e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}\left(4 x^{4}+2 x^{2}\left(2 y^{2}-5\right)-2 y^{2}+2\right)=\\
e^{-(x^{2}+y^{2})}\left(4 x^{2}(x^2+y^2)-10x^2-2 y^{2}+2\right)=\\
e^{-1}(-4x^2-2(x^2+y^2)+2)=-4x^2e^{-1}<0\\
f_{yy}=e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}\left(x^{2}\left(4 y^{2}-2\right)+4 y^{4}-10 y^{2}+2\right)=\cdots=\\
-4y^2e^{-1}<0\\
f_{xy}=4 x y e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}-2\right)=-4xye^{-1}\\
D=f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}=(-4x^2e^{-1})(-4y^2e^{-1})-(-4xye^{-1})^2=0$$
According to [this](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Second_derivative_test_for_a_function_of_two_variables) (case 5), it is inconclusive, but not minimum.

Consider the small neighborhood of $x^2+y^2=1$ (at this point $f(x,y)=e^{-1}$):
$$x^2+y^2=1\pm \varepsilon, \varepsilon>0\\
f(x,y)=\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right) e^{-\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}=(1-\varepsilon)e^{-(1-\varepsilon)}<e^{-1} \iff e^{-\varepsilon}>1-\varepsilon\\
f(x,y)=\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right) e^{-\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)}=(1+\varepsilon)e^{-(1+\varepsilon)}<e^{-1} \iff e^{\varepsilon}>1+\varepsilon$$
Hence, the points of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ are the local maximum points.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

The function is purely radial:

$$f(r) = r^2 e^{-r^2}$$

and the derivatives are straightforward:

$$\frac{\partial f(r)}{\partial r} = -2 e^{-r^2} r \left(r^2-1\right)$$

Set it to zero to find the extrema are at $r=0$ or $r=1$.

[image]

Comment: I'd just like to add that ${\partial f \over \partial \theta} = 0$ at every point, so whether it's a minimum or a maximum is determined here solely by the second derivative in the radial direction.

Comment: the link doesnt work

Comment: When I click the link, I see that ''Secure Connection Failed

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.''

Comment: @Pozcu what link? I don't see a link present in David's answer.

Comment: Now, i can see the graph